# How can I use an action filter in ASP.NET MVC to route to a different view but using the same URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to make a filter that, after a controller action has been (mostly) processed, checks for a certain test condition and routes to a different view transparently to the user (i.e., no change in the URL)?

Here would be my best guess at some pseudocode:

```
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // If some condition is true
        //  Change the resulting view resolution to XYZ

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/SomeController/SomeView.cshtml"
};
```

This will short-circuit the execution of the action.

Answer (score 1):

also you can return view as from your action

```
  public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    return View(@"~/Views/SomeView.aspx");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the `AuthorizeAttribute` of ASP.NET MVC action filter as DCIMAuthorize, in which I perform some security checks and if user is not authenticated or authorized then action filter will take user to access denied page. My implementation is as below:

```
public class DCIMAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public string BusinessComponent { get; set; }

    public string Action { get; set; }
    public bool ResturnJsonResponse { get; set; }
    public bool Authorize { get; set; }

    public DCIMAuthorize()
    {
        ResturnJsonResponse = true;
    }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        try
        {
            //to check whether user is authenticated
            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;
            //to check site level access
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSites"] != null)
            {
                var allSites = (VList<VSiteList>)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSites"];
                if (allSites.Count <= 0)
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;

            // use Authorize for authorization
            Authorize = false;

            string[] roles = null;
            //get roles for currently login user
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Roles"] != null)
            {
                roles = (string[])HttpContext.Current.Session["Roles"];
            }

            if (roles != null)
            {
                //for multiple roles
                string[] keys = new string[roles.Length];
                int index = 0;
                // for each role, there is separate key
                foreach (string role in roles)
                {
                    keys[index] = role + "-" + BusinessComponent + "-" + Action;
                    index++;
                }

                //access Authorization Details and compare with keys  
                if (HttpContext.Current.Application["AuthorizationDetails"] != null)
                {
                    Hashtable authorizationDetails = (Hashtable)HttpContext.Current.Application["AuthorizationDetails"];

                    bool hasKey = false;
                    foreach (var item in keys)
                    {
                        hasKey = authorizationDetails.ContainsKey(item);
                        if (hasKey)
                        {
                            Authorize = hasKey;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["ResturnJsonResponse"] = ResturnJsonResponse;
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // auth failed, redirect to login page
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

                return;
            }

            if (!Authorize)
            {
                //Authorization failed, redirect to Access Denied Page
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new RouteValueDictionary{{ "controller", "Base" },
                                             { "action", "AccessDenied" }
                                             //{ "returnUrl",    filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl }
                                            });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, and wrapped up into a reusable attribute and the great thing is it retains the original URL while redirecting (or applying whatever result you wish) based on your requirements:

```
public class AuthoriseSiteAccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        // Perform your condition, or straight result assignment here.
        // For me I had to test the existance of a cookie.
        if (yourConditionHere)
            filterContext.Result = new SiteAccessDeniedResult();
    }

}

public class SiteAccessDeniedResult : ViewResult
{
    public SiteAccessDeniedResult()
    {
        ViewName = "~/Views/SiteAccess/Login.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Then just add the attribute `[SiteAccessAuthorise]` to your controllers you wish to apply the authorisation access to (in my case) or add it to a BaseController. Make sure though the action you are redirecting to's underlying controller does not have the attribute though, or you'll be caught in an endless loop!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Save All Route File Path in a Static And Use it Like This :

```
public static class ViewPath
{
    public const string SomeViewName = "~/Views/SomeViewName.cshtml";
    //...
}
```

And into Your ActionFilter :

```
        context.Result = new ViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = ViewPath.SomeViewName /*"~/Views/SomeViewName.cshtml"*/
        };
```